# Converting rtf to pdf using python

Tags: python, pdf, rtf

I am new to the python language and I am given a task to convert rtf to pdf using python. I googled and found some code- (not exactly rtf to pdf) but I tried working on it and changed it according to my requirement. But I am not able to solve it.

I have used the below code:

```
import sys
import os
import comtypes.client
#import win32com.client
rtfFormatPDF = 17

in_file = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])
out_file = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[2])

rtf= comtypes.client.CreateObject('Rtf.Application')

rtf.Visible = True
doc = rtf.Documents.Open(in_file)
doc.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=rtfFormatPDF)
doc.Close()
rtf.Quit()
```

But its throwing the below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/Lib/idlelib/rtf_to_pdf.py", line 12, in <module>
    word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Rtf.Application')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 227, in CreateObject
    clsid = comtypes.GUID.from_progid(progid)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\comtypes\GUID.py", line 78, in from_progid
    _CLSIDFromProgID(str(progid), byref(inst))
  File "_ctypes/callproc.c", line 920, in GetResult
OSError: [WinError -2147221005] Invalid class string
```

Can anyone help me with this?
I would really appreciate if someone can find the better and fast way of doing it. I have around 200,000 files to convert.

Anisha

Comment: Where did you get the information that "Rtf.Application" was a valid com object? I would guess you found some code for converting a Word document to PDF and just replaced "Word.Application" by "Rtf.Application".

Comment: yes. That is true! tried finding a replacement for this, but no luck!

Comment: Do you require a _python_ solution or just a solution for your 200,000 files?  If python is not a requirement, try LibreOffice:  `libreoffice --headless -convert-to pdf filename.rtf`

Comment: @Carsten so that makes a point, what if the ProgID were set back to "Word.Application", think it would work?

Comment: Well, python is not mandatory, I can try using LibreOffice. So this means there is no solution in Python?

Comment: @MarkRansom Yep, just tried it. Works like a charm if you change the com object back to "Word.Application" to let Word handle the conversion. It can open RTFs without problems. Also, OP refers to the same variable once as `rtfFormatPDF` and once as `wdFormatPDF` (not sure why) so that would have to be changed as well.

Comment: Thanks @Carsten !! That was a typo. Sorry! I will try working with "Word.Application" and see how it goes with Rtfs'.

Comment: It worked! thanks! Will add the working code!

Comment: Please don't edit your working code into the question. We like to keep questions and answers separate. Please edit it into the answer you provided below instead.

Comment: ok. changed it! Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used Marks's advice and changed it back to Word.Application and my source pointing to rtf files. Works perfectly! - the process was slow but still faster than the JAVA application which my team was using. I have attached the final code in my question.

Final Code:
Got it done using the code which works with Word application :

```
import sys
import os,os.path
import comtypes.client

wdFormatPDF = 17

input_dir = 'input directory'
output_dir = 'output directory'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(input_dir):
    for file in files:
        in_file = os.path.join(subdir, file)
        output_file = file.split('.')[0]
        out_file = output_dir+output_file+'.pdf'
        word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')

        doc = word.Documents.Open(in_file)
        doc.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)
        doc.Close()
        word.Quit()
```

Comment: `os.path.splitext` can be better choice for getting file name without extension

Comment: does it required to install MS word to use this.

Comment: @RohitGupta Yes, it does

Comment: For processing many files I found it was quicker to init word outside the for loops, then .Close() each doc and open the next one with the same word process, finally .Quit() after loops.

Comment: make sure to remove space between files name

Answer (score 1):

If you have Libre Office in your system, you got the best solution.

```py
import os
os.system('soffice --headless --convert-to pdf filename.rtf')
# os.system('libreoffice --headless -convert-to pdf filename.rtf')
# os.system('libreoffice6.3 --headless -convert-to pdf filename.rtf')
```

Commands may vary to different versions and platforms. But this would be the best solution ever I had.

Answer (score -1):

Probably the easiest way is a simple command line to convert an rtf file to pdf format (if you have libreoffice installed) which you can also easily use in a Python script (using "os.system(...)" example or "subprocess.getoutput(...)" option. The simple command line in Linux is:

> libreoffice  --headless  --convert-to  pdf  filename.rtf

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).